# Category of UserControl, CustomControl property

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, controls

I'm developer my new `CustomControl`, I know when I put `[Caterogy("MyCategeory")]` on the property, it will create a new category in the property List in design mode

Example:

```
[Category("Mask")]
public string Mask
{
    get
    {
        return _Mask;
    }
    set
    {
        this._Mask = value;
    }
}
```

What name is this? How to I can search about it? I want meet others features for customize my control property, but I don't know how to called it and I don't know what more can I do for customize my properties

Example, how to can I set a property contains get, set, but no show in the property list?

Answer (score 1):

**Category** is an example of an [Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Google "C# Attributes" and you should find a load of references to help you explore.